# Convert List of 1 element to Option

Tags: scala, collections, converters, scala-option

Let's say I have a List[T] from which I need a single element, and I'd like to convert it to an Option.

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
list.take(1).find(_=>true) // Some(1)

val empty = List.empty
empty.take(1).find(_=>true) // None
```

This would appear to be somewhat of a hack ;-)

What's a better approach to converting a single element List to an Option?

Comment: When you have doubts like that it could be useful to look at http://scalex.org/ as well. It's kind of type search for scala, similar to haskell's hoogle.
You just type signature of function which you are looking for and it tries to find every function which could match.
In this case just try 'List[A] => Option[A]' and you will see headOption as second result.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Scala provides a `headOption` method that does exactly what you want:

```
scala> List(1).headOption
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> List().headOption
res1: Option[Nothing] = None
```

Comment: and `toList` applied to an `Option` is the inverse of it

Answer (score 16):

`headOption` is what you need:

```
scala> List.empty.headOption
res0: Option[Nothing] = None

scala> List(1,2,3).take(1).headOption
res1: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Comment: @virtualeyes Please accept winwingedsubmariner's answer as his answer seems to be 10 seconds ahead. I will delete mine.

Comment: done, although, you should both get credit, essentially answered at the same time